# Create Google Form from XML file

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have tree structure in XML file and I want to dynamically generate the Google Form from that XML file. I can't find anything about this kind of stuff, only how to import XML to Google Sheet, but it seems impossible to create Form from Sheet. Do you have any idea how-to ?

Comment: Give us a copy of your XML file, it depends what is on it but it seems possible to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Google Apps Script's [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) you can dynamically create forms. The flow could be as follows:

1. Parse the your XML file using [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service).
2. Create a form using the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms), with the [`FormApp.create()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#create(String)) method.
3. Iterate over your XML tree and add items to your form accordingly, using methods such as [`addTextItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addTextItem()) or [`addCheckboxItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addCheckboxItem()).
4. Get your form's published URL with the [`getPublishedUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getpublishedurl) method. You may also share it using the [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail).

You can see an example on creating a form on the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) page.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, but can you explain where I need to run the code in order to generate Forms with app script?

Comment: @demo no worries:) You can create, run and debug your code all from the Google Apps Script editor (see https://script.google.com). I suggest you follow the 'hello world' project if it's your first time using Google Apps Script. (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)